# Adapter pattern or Composition?

Tags: java, oop

I want to use external library from gitHub in cleaner way

```
public class Sgtin { full of fields and methods including encode and decode }
```

in my class Decoder I would like to have only 2 methods from several implemented in object

```
public class Decoder {

private static final Sgtin sgtin = new Sgtin();

public static String encode(String ean, Long serialNumber, int filterValue) {
    return sgtin.encode(ean, serialNumber, filterValue);
}

public static Sgtin decode(String cpe) {
    return sgtin.decode(cpe);
}
```

}

I would like to hide the Sgtin class in mthod decode (in case I would make any modifications in it, I wont have to change the original class) so in aim to do that, I create some other object (Decoder) and map Sgtin to it? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: `Object` is really not a good name to name the class you want to wrap.

Comment: Thank You, You are right -  I changed the name to Sgtin. Do You think both methods can be static?

Comment: Hard to answer if we don't know how sgtin is really used. Do you invoke static or instance methods of this class ?

Comment: Which library is that? Would be interesting for me.

Comment: Sgtin is just public class I found online and Copy it to my package where I have Decoder class and trying to use it in more ellegant way, hiding the "engine and mess" included in sgtin class.

Comment: I used this: https://github.com/impinj/itemsense-hybris-datahub-java/blob/master/datahub/impinj/impinj-canonical/src/main/java/com/impinj/datahub/itemsense/Sgtin96.java

Comment: And combine it with https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/105121/sgtin96-encode-for-epc-on-rfid

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `Decoder` class to implement the Singleton pattern. Either you are missing some code there, because it should actually throw a NPE since `sgtin` is not initialized.

But your approach is fine as it is.

Comment: @Anna You did not initialize it anywhere. Right now it is just a declaration. That's why I said it should throw an npe.

Comment: @Anna As you said it yourself you need to use `= new Sgtin()`.

Comment: @Anna Yes like that

Comment: @Anna yes in different way. you could do it in better way by dependency injection.

Comment: Ok, so can I say that this is an example of using Pattern Object Adapter? I noticed in different sources that the methods implied are void and the Sgtin class might be extended by Decoder.